# Delphi 64 bits Insert rtf stream into richedit

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, rtf

I try to insert a rtf inside a richedit (specifically a rtf saved in database, and then inserted in the current richedit control at the selection point).

The code below works in 32 bits. But was not able to make it work in 64 bits, even by reading different replies in google in other languages.

I think I have somewhere the wrong size of some types.

Thanks already for helping me.

Version Delphi 10.4 (But I don't think it is relevant)

```
type
  TEditStreamCallBack = function(dwCookie: Longint; pbBuff: PByte;  
    cb: Longint; var pcb: Longint): DWORD;  
  stdcall;

  TEditStream = record
    dwCookie: Longint;
    dwError: Longint;
    pfnCallback: TEditStreamCallBack;
  end;

  TpRichEditUtils = class
  public
    class procedure RTFInsertStream(const ARichEdit : TRichEdit; const AStream: TStream);
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.RichEdit, SysUtils;

function EditStreamReader(dwCookie: DWORD; pBuff: Pointer; cb: LongInt; pcb: PLongInt): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  Result := $0000;  // assume no error
  try
    pcb^ := TStream(dwCookie).Read(pBuff^, cb); // read data from stream
  except
    Result := $FFFF;  // indicates error to calling routine
  end;
end;

class procedure TpRichEditUtils.RTFInsertStream(const ARichEdit : TRichEdit; const AStream: TStream);
var
  EditStream: TEditStream;  // callback used to read inserted RTF
begin
  ARichEdit.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    // Make sure rich edit is large enough to take inserted code
    ARichEdit.MaxLength := ARichEdit.MaxLength + AStream.Size;
    // Stream in the RTF via EM_STREAMIN message
    EditStream.dwCookie := DWORD(AStream);
    EditStream.dwError := $0000;
    EditStream.pfnCallback := @EditStreamReader;
    ARichEdit.Perform(
      EM_STREAMIN,
      SFF_SELECTION or SF_RTF or SFF_PLAINRTF, LPARAM(@EditStream)
    );
    // Report any errors as a bug
    if EditStream.dwError <> $0000 then
      raise Exception.Create('RTFInsertStream: Error inserting stream');
  finally
    ARichEdit.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

OStream := TStringStream.Create(ODmRemarqueStandard.REMSTD_TEXTE);
try
  TpRichEditUtils.RTFInsertStream(TcxRichInnerEdit(EdtConditionGenerale.InnerControl), OStream);
finally
  FreeAndNil(OStream)
end;
```

I tried changing the dwCookie: Longint to DWORD_PTR. and tried other things, but always access violation.

Comment: Your and `TEditStreamCalback` function and `TEditStream` record definitions differ from those that are already declared within `Winapi.RichEdit` unit. There `TEditStreamCalback` result type is defined as `Longint` yet you declare it as `DWORD` and `TEditStream` field `dwCookie` is defined as `DWORD_PTR` and yet you define it as `Longint`. Any way why are you even redeclaring these types if they are already defined in `Winapi.RichEdit` that you are including in implementation uses section?

Comment: The correct return type for the [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/nc-richedit-editstreamcallback) is `DWORD`, not `Longint`.  And indeed, `dwCookie` should be `DWORD_PTR` not `longint` (and `dwError` should be `DWORD`).  One thing that is missing in the manual declaration of `TEditStreamCalback` is `stdcall` in 32bit.

Comment: You should look at the source code for `TRichEdit` in `Vcl.ComCtrls.pas` to see how it implements `EM_STREAMIN`.

Comment: @SilverWarior I didnt know these were already in a delphi source -_-;

Comment: @MichaelDesboeufs To be honest I also didn't knew that until yesterday since I have never used `Winapi.RichEdit` unit myself. At least not by adding it to uses section myself. Heck I didn't even knew it exists until I saw it referenced in your code. But as soon as I sow it in your code I opened my Delphi and went and check the unit source code to se how it is implemented. It is at that time I noticed discrepancy between your declaration and the one in the `Winapi.RichEdit` unit. ...

Comment: ... So unless you are using Community Edition of Delphi you should also have access to the source code of most of the units that ship with Delphi. You can learn a lot by checking their source code.

Comment: @SilverWarior Of course, it is good to learn from others.  I read their code from time to time. It is sometimes not so easy to read and interpret code from other people. From my lack of knowledge or wrong interpretation of what it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TEditStreamCallBack` and `EditStreamReader` declarations do not match.

Also, you are handling the cookie as a 32bit integer in both 32bit and 64bit builds, which is wrong. It needs to be a 32bit integer in a 32bit build, and a 64bit integer in a 64bit build.  The Win32 API declares the cookie as a `DWORD_PTR` for exactly that purpose.

`TEditStreamCallBack` and `TEditStream` are already declared in the `Winapi.RichEdit` unit, you do not need to declare them manually in your own code.

Try this instead:

```
uses
  Winapi.RichEdit, SysUtils;

function EditStreamReader(dwCookie: DWORD_PTR; pbBuff: PByte; cb: Longint; var pcb: Longint): Longint; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 0;  // assume no error
  try
    pcb := TStream(dwCookie).Read(pBuff^, cb); // read data from stream
  except
    Result := -1;  // indicates error to calling routine
  end;
end;

class procedure TpRichEditUtils.RTFInsertStream(const ARichEdit : TRichEdit; const AStream: TStream);
var
  EditStream: TEditStream;  // callback used to read inserted RTF
begin
  ARichEdit.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    // Make sure rich edit is large enough to take inserted code
    ARichEdit.MaxLength := ARichEdit.MaxLength + AStream.Size;
    // Stream in the RTF via EM_STREAMIN message
    EditStream.dwCookie := DWORD_PTR(AStream);
    EditStream.dwError := 0;
    EditStream.pfnCallback := @EditStreamReader;
    ARichEdit.Perform(
      EM_STREAMIN,
      SFF_SELECTION or SF_RTF or SFF_PLAINRTF,
      LPARAM(@EditStream)
    );
    // Report any errors as a bug
    if EditStream.dwError <> 0 then
      raise Exception.Create('RTFInsertStream: Error inserting stream');
  finally
    ARichEdit.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't see the types were already defined in WinApi.RichEdit. It solved my problem.  Thank you again for your great answer.